# Scrapy json modifying array

Tags: python, arrays, json, scrapy

Using Scrapy I have the data off the website that I want in json form, the end result being I want to POST this data to a database using rest api, so it has to have certain keys in a certain form.

I'm trying to get the data into this json form; the ONLY array can be under attribute, all other have to be one to one keys and values.

```
{
"Event":{
"date":"2015-11-25",
"threat_level_id":"1",
"info":"TEST",
"analysis":"0",
"distribution":"0",
"orgc":"Malware, Inc",
"Attribute": [
{
"type":"md5",
"category":"Payload delivery",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"35b759347aee663e36f5b91877749349"},
{"type":"url",
"category":"Network activity",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"conf.f.360.cn"},
{
"type":"ip-dst",
"category":"Network activity",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"1.1.1.1"}]
}
}
```

*The array "Attribute" could have several items in it.  The problem I'm getting is I can't create the 'Attribute' array for more than one object,  I'm not sure how add mulitiple types that look alike and contain the same 'keys'.

This doesn't work...

```
def parse_items(self, response):
          self.log("Hi, this is an item page! %s" % response.url)
          item = Website()
          item["date"] = "current date"
          item["threat_level_id"] = "1"
          item["info"] = "Malware"
          item["analysis"] = 0
          item["distribution"] = 0
          item["orgc"] = "Malware"
          item["Attribute"] = {}
          item["Attribute"]['type'] = "ip-dst"
          item["Attribute"]["category"] ="Network activity"
          item["Attribute"]["to-ids"] = True
          item["Attribute"]["distribution"] = "3"
          item["Attribute"]['ip']  = response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-   hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()
          item["Attribute"]['type'] = "domain"
          item["Attribute"]["category"] ="Network activity"
          item["Attribute"]["to-ids"] = True
          item["Attribute"]["distribution"] = "3"
          item["Attribute"]['domain'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="dns-requests"]//a/text()').extract()
          item["Attribute"]['type'] = "md5"
          item["Attribute"]["category"] ="Payload delivery"
          item["Attribute"]["to-ids"] = True
          item["Attribute"]["distribution"] = "3"
          item["Attribute"]['md5'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "MD5")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')[0].extract()
```

This returns a jumble like this

```
[ 
[
[
{"info": "Website",
"orgc": "Malware",
"analysis": 0,
"Attribute": {"category": "Payload delivery",
"domain": ["anatolio69.no-ip.biz", "lucidspung.com", "swashsepal.com"],        #Gotta get this array to a one to one value as well
"to-ids": true,
"ip": ["190.127.234.120"],
"distribution": "3",
"type": "md5",
"md5": "28e59d011c6103b5f5330b5ad042bdba"},
"date": "current date",
"distribution": 0,
"threat_level_id": "1"},
```

How do i break up the arrays that "ip" and "domain" return and get "Attribute" to hold all the same values like this --

```
{
"Event":{
"date":"2015-11-25",
"threat_level_id":"1",
"info":"TEST",
"analysis":"0",
"distribution":"0",
"orgc":"Malware, Inc",
"Attribute": [
{
"type":"md5",
"category":"Payload delivery",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"35b759347aee663e36f5b91877749349"},
{"type":"url",
"category":"Network activity",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"conf.f.360.cn"},
{
"type":"ip-dst",
"category":"Network activity",
"to_ids":true,
"distribution":"3",
"value":"1.1.1.1"}]
}
}
```

I would appreciate it... I really am not sure how to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attribute` key in the JSON should contain an array of dictionaries. You should first initialize the array and then assign the values like given below:

```
item["Attribute"] = []
item["Attribute"].append({'type':"ip-dst"})
item["Attribute"][0]["category"] ="Network activity"
item["Attribute"][0]["to-ids"] = True
item["Attribute"][0]["distribution"] = "3"
item["Attribute"][0]['ip']  = response.xpath('//*[@id="contacted-   hosts"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()

item["Attribute"].append({'type':"domain"})
item["Attribute"][1]["category"] ="Network activity"
item["Attribute"][1]["to-ids"] = True
item["Attribute"][1]["distribution"] = "3"
item["Attribute"][1]['domain'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="dns-requests"]//a/text()').extract()

item["Attribute"].append({'type':"md5"})
item["Attribute"][2]["category"] ="Payload delivery"
item["Attribute"][2]["to-ids"] = True
item["Attribute"][2]["distribution"] = "3"
item["Attribute"][2]['md5'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "MD5")]/following-sibling::dd[1]/text()')[0].extract()
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That works.  Not sure what I'd do without stack overflow.